# both @JsonProperty @JsonIgnore annotation for the same field

Tags: java, jackson

I wonder what Jackson should do, when there are both @JsonProperty @JsonIgnore annotation for 1 field

```java
    @JsonProperty @JsonIgnore private boolean isSuperUser;
```

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, but this seems very easy to just try.